# Configure Puppeteer to download Chromium Binary instead of compiling it

Tags: heroku, chromium, devops, puppeteer, buildpack

We use `puppeteer` for headless rendering on Ubuntu. More specifically, this is via [a buildpack](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) on Heroku.

Unfortunately our new deployments are quite slow as puppeteer seems to download Chromium prerequisites and compile Chromium from scratch every time.

Is there any way to skip the compile step / configure Puppeteer to **download an existing binary** (e.g. [from here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)) instead?

If not, could we potentially cache the self-compiled binary so it only needs to be updated when we update our puppeteer version?

Comment: Puppeteer does not compile Chromium. It [downloads a binary](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#installation), so it should be doing exactly what you want. I just compiled Chromium once and it took literally hours. Are you sure your application is actually compiling Chromium?

Comment: No I'm not sure @ThomasDondorf I had assumed it was in this case due to prerequisite library downloading and long slug compile times, but perhaps that's actually something else. Fair point that Chromium could take much longer still, so thanks for the clarification. I'll investigate a bit closer to see what's going.